# Recovering Files on Windows and C

Tags: c++, c, windows

Well this time I'm trying to write a program in C which recover deleted files from a disk, it could be an external disk, I have an idea than i had used before on linux, it is to open the disk as a kind of file and scaning the Headers and file footers of everything within the disk, the point is I'm not sure if there's allow on windows to open a disk as an File, basiclly I have the logic how to develope this program, but I'm not sure how to implement it on windows, anybody can give me a hand with this?.

The code I used on linux to open a disk as a file was:
Edit: That was a sample of what I was using guys, it's just to give you an idea of what I was doing, the correct syntax I used was the next:

```
direccion = ui->linea->text().toLatin1().constData();
f = fopen(direccion,"rb");
```

I used QT creator on linux, and direccion variable was a TextField value which contained the file path of the disk through a button function that open a QFileDialog...

could I use it in windows as well?

Thank you before hand..

Comment: _"The code I used on linux to open a disk ..."_ **linux** with _drive characters `E:`_ and unescaped backslash `\\` path delimiter?? That sounds seriously strange, and I doubt you can present any running code.from this using a linux host environment.

Comment: I don't know if you can `fopen()` a physical drive, but you can open it with the Win32 API [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) function (despite its name, it can open several kinds of resources, not just files).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Does `CreateFile()` work with deleted files?  The question is about recovering deleted files.

Comment: To recover deleted files, you have to access the file system directly and parse/alter its file records accordingly.  And also parse the raw partition data directly so you can find the deleted files, since they are not in the file system anymore (unless the file system keep track of them). You can do that stuff with `CreateFile()`/`ReadFile()`/`WriteFile()`, but you have to be VERY careful working at such a low level of data.  There are a bazillion recovery tools already widely available, I would not recommend writing a new one, except maybe as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

> *"The code I used on linux to open a disk as a file was:"*
>
> ```
>  File *f = fopen("E:\", "rb");
> ```

I seriously doubt you ever got this code working on any linux system (or windows either).
You'll need to escape the backslash path delimiter, if it's presented in any string literal:

```
FILE* f = fopen("E:\\", "rb");
                // ^
```

---

Also all that filesystem path style you are presenting to access a particular disk, is about accessing a windows file path/disk.

No linux file system has notion about *drive characters*, and the file path delimiter value used is `'/'`, not `'\\'`.

Answer (score 0):

To recover deleted files, you can't use `fopen` or `fstream::open` because the file was deleted.  Check the return value from the function or test the stream state.

The way to recover deleted files is:

1. Get the Master File Table as raw data.
2. Search for the record containing a string similar to the deleted
   filename.
3. Change the entry in the Master File Table to "undeleted".
4. Write the Master File Table back to the drive.

The above usually requires platform specific API, which is different on Linux and Windows platforms.

Comment: Thanks for you step list input, the points is than I've  never try to do a thing like this before, so I'm not really sure about how to do it, I doesn't even program on c/c++ so much, could you help me with an example of it or a guide about how to getting those data (Master File Table) so I can use it as a bridge to solve my target?

Comment: Post to SuperUser@StackExchange.com